# How to Clear Fields using reset in  struts 1.x after redirect to same page?

Tags: html, struts, reset

I'm using struts1.3.8. I'm using struts provided elements like ,.
Reset is working until i don't click on login page i.e,Before form submit.Once i press login and login failed, Redirecting to same page.In this moment reset is not working.So How to Empty the fields after redirect to same page when i click on reset button?
Thanks
Laxman Chowdary

Comment: Not clear. JS reset function restores original inputs values (values fields got when page was loaded). If you redirect so some page and fields values get another values, hope you are not expecting to restore values from original page.

Comment: Hi antaella, Redirecting to same page.i.e, Login page only.After redirecting it is not clearing the fields when i click on reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset function doesn't clean fields. Reset function restores original values. If an input is loaded with a value and you change this value and then click on "Reset", original value will be displayed, not empty value.

If what you want is to clean fields when you you click on a button, you should implement a function that do that, going through all form inputs and setting empty values.

Comment: The Form fields are in session.I have to delete the session when i click on reset button. How to implement it?

Comment: You sure? Did you put them into session? I bet values are in the request, not in the session. You should delete them from the struts action, not from the page using JS. By the way, if what you want, is just use simple HTML inputs (instead struts inputs) with "value" set to "" (empty)

Comment: I do not see the point, but if you want to delete session attributes from a page you should implement a AJAX petition, so when user clicks on "reset" you call (using AJAX) a action/controller that remove attributes from session.

Comment: I emptied the session but no use.. Still displaying the field values when redirected to the same page.

Comment: If what you really what (not clear) is fields not to be displayed with a previous value, clean the user/pass request attributes in your action (setting them to "") or user simple HTML inputs (not struts inputs tags)